# What exactly are "containers" in python? (And what are all the python container types?)

Tags: python, containers

The python documentation frequently speaks of "containers". [E.g.](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html?highlight=container#basic-usage) :

> If check_circular is False (default: True), then the circular
>   reference check for **container types** will be skipped and a circular
>   reference will result in an OverflowError (or worse).

But I can't find any official definition of containers, neither a list of them.

### Edit

For Python 2.7.3:

**Checked builtin types which are containers:**

(`isinstance(object, collections.Container)` returns `True`)

1. Containers which have a `__contains__` method defined:

   - All builtin sequence types: Lists, bytearrays, strings, unicode strings and 
     tuples.
   - Dictionaries
   - All builtin set types: sets and frozensets
2. Containers which do not have a `__contains__` method defined:

   - xrange objects

**Checked builtin types which are not containers:**

(`isinstance(object, collections.Container)` returns `False`):

- Int objects
- Float objects
- Long objects
- Boolean objects
- Module objects
- File objects
- Buffer objects
- The None object

Tell me which other builtin types you have checked for `isinstance(object, collections.Container)`  and I'll add them to the list.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Containers are any object that holds an arbitrary number of other objects.  Generally, containers provide a way to access the contained objects and to iterate over them.

Examples of containers include `tuple`, `list`, `set`, `dict`; these are the *built-in containers*.  More container types are available in the [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#module-collections) module.

Strictly speaking, the [`collections.abc.Container`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Container) abstract base class ([`collections.Container`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Container) in Python2) holds for any type that supports the `in` operator via the `__contains__` magic method; so if you can write `x in y` then `y` is *usually* a container, but not always: an important point of difference between *containers* and general *iterables* is that when iterated over, containers will return existing objects that they hold a reference to, while generators and e.g. `file` objects will create a new object each time.  This has implications for garbage collection and deep object traversal (e.g. `deepcopy` and serialisation).

As an example, `iter(lambda: random.choice(range(6)), 0)` supports the `in` operator, but it is certainly *not* a container!

The intent of the `Collections.abc.Container` abstract base class in only considering the `__contains__` magic method and not other ways of supporting the `in` operator is that a true container should be able to test for containment in a single operation and without observably changing internal state.  Since `Collections.abc.Container` defines `__contains__` as an abstract method, you are guaranteed that if `isinstance(x, collections.abc.Container)` then `x` supports the `in` operator.

In practice, then, all containers will have the `__contains__` magic method. However, when testing whether an object is a container you should use `isinstance(x, collections.abc.Container)` for clarity and for forward compatibility should the `Container` subclass check ever be changed.

Comment: I think this answer is not correct, because it does not handle the opposite. Example:
`>>> a = "hello"
>>> isinstance(a, collections.abc.Container)
True
>>> 
`
So, the problem is: How to find out that a container is not some basestring? One solution would be to check exactly that.

Answer (score 10):

According to http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc, the most general definition of a container is simply an object that implements `__contains__`.  In general, Python concepts like "container" or "sequence" are not defined abstractly; they are "duck-typed" by their behavior.  That is, a container is something that you can use the `in` operator on.

The Python builtin container types are tuple, list, dict, set, frozenset and str and unicode (or bytes and str in Python 3), as well as a couple other constructs that are technically types but are not commonly used outside of specific contexts (e.g., buffer objects and xrange objects).  Additional container types are provided in the `collections` module.

Comment: `dir(xrange)` does not return a `__contains__` method. Neither does `dir(buffer)`

Comment: Containers are a little more broad than that; they're anything that supports testing via `in`. See http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details

Answer (score 0):

Container are all python objects that contain other object like `list` or `dict`. The `Container` type is an ABC, it behave like an interface. A Container is a class that implements the `__contains__` method.

Here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)