# How do you store two different inputs from the same variable?

Tags: python

```
    while n == 1:
        w = input("Input the product code: ")
```

Problem is that when a new code for w is entered, w is overwritten. For example, if w = 24, then w = 54, if you print(w) it will just print 54, since it's the latest input. How do you make it so that it prints all inputs for w?

Comment: Use a list for `w` instead and just append each entry?

Comment: Could you not print it as you are taking the inputs in? Also the only way you can storage 2 different things in a variable is if it's a set or a class or some sort of containers, unless you concat your values together and store it into the string but that get messy and too much overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container type instead of a single variable. In this case, `list()` would seem appropriate:

```
inputs = [] # use a list to add each input value to
while n == 1:
    inputs.append(input("Input the product code: ")) # each time the user inputs a string, added it to the inputs list
for i in inputs: # for each item in the inputs list
    print(i) # print the item
```

**Note:** The above code will not compile. You need to fill in the value for the variable `n`.

Comment: OH THATS HOW IT WORKS

Comment: @Anya Yes. Although keep in mind that a list is not your only option for a container type. I suggest reading the [up on Python container types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575925/what-exactly-are-containers-in-python-and-what-are-all-the-python-container).

Answer (score 1):

```
inputs = []
for i in range(expected_number_of_inputs):
    inputs.append(input('Product Code: '))
for i in inputs:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two separate ways but the way you are trying to do it will not work. You cannot have a variable that is not a list hold two values.

Solution 1: use two variables

```
w1 = input("value1")
w2 = input("value2")
print(w1)
print(w2)
```

Solution 2: use a list

```
w = []
w.append(input("value1"))
w.append(input("value2"))
print(w[0])
print(w[1])
```

Comment: Your solution 2 will give an `IndexError`. Use `w.append(input())`