# Parent/children class structure in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, superclass

I'm currently working on a pricing tool which has several level of calculations.

For instance, I have an object Quote which itself has one or several QuoteItem attached.

I think there should be class inheritance but I don't want to initialize my Quote every time I create a QuoteItem since all QuoteItems share exactly the same Quote with the same characteristics.

Is that class inheritance with super class ? Or should it be 2 independent class ?
I can't find any documentation nor resource dealing about my scenario which I think to be very common.

I have a list of quoteitems which are attached to one quote, I would like first to create the quote and then the quoteitems. If I start from the quoteitems I feel that it will create everytime a quote which isn't at all the expected behaviour since there should be only 1 quote for all my quoteitems.

Is that a correct approach ?

```
class Quote():
    def __init__():
        # this will set parameter global to the quote
        print('Quote created')


class QuoteItem(Quote):
    def __init__():
        # this will set specific details for all quote items attached to one specific quote
        print ('QuoteItem created')
```

Or should those 2 classes be totally independent ?

Any use case or documentation about such scenario is welcome.
The parent/subclass document I found deals only with object which are very similar. In my example they are not the same, they are children, i.e quoteitems can't exist without quote.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When thinking of inheritance, you're using an "is-a" relationship.

```py
class Vehicle(object):  # a Vehicle IS AN object
    pass
class Car(Vehicle):     # a Car     IS A  Vehicle
    pass
class Sedan(Car):       # A Sedan   IS A  Car
    pass
```

What you're probably looking for in a quote and its items is a "has-a" relationship.

```py
class Tire(object):     # a Tire IS AN object, but...
    pass

class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, num_tires=4):
        self.tires = [Tire() for _ in num_tires]
                        # a Vehicle HAS A Tire  (or in this case 4 tires)
```

To extend the metaphor for your specific use case:

```py
class QuoteItem(object):
    def __init__(self, modelnumber, quantity, totalprice):
        self.modelnumber = modelnumber
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.totalprice = totalprice
        # I'm guessing at what you'd want here


class Quote(object):
    _last_quote_number = 0

    @property
    @classmethod
    def next_quote_number(cls) -> int:
        cls._last_quote_number += 1
        return cls._last_quote_number

    def __init__(self, customerid):
        self.number = self.next_quote_number
        self.customerid = customerid
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, modelnumber, quantity, totalprice) -> None:
        item = QuoteItem(modelnumber, quantity, totalprice)
        self.items.append(item)
```

Comment: That is very clear thank you ! This answers my point as to how I create subitems. I call a method from the Quote class which will call the QuoteItem class. I wasn't sure this was best practice but that's fine now.
If there are many quoteitems to create at once, what should I do ? should I send a list and have the method in Quote converting the list into a for loop ? or should the deagregation made in the QuoteItem list ? or should the for loop made when calling the add_item method ?

Comment: What I've used in the past is to make another `classmethod` that's essentially an alternate constructor that is smart enough to do something like parse a list (or read from a csv or etc). Then that method would do `quoteitem = cls(customerid); for modelnumber, quantity, totalprice in parsed_item_details: quoteitem.add_item(modelnumber, quantity, totalprice); return quoteitem`. Then you can create a `Quote` from your list of items with `quote = Quote.yournewclassmethod(customerid, list_of_items)`

Answer (score 2):

Using inheritance here isn't the best approach. Just let `Quote` have a container (for example a list) with all of its QuoteItems.

When using inheritance like this, you are saying a `QuoteItem` is a special sort of `Quote` which it isn't. `QuoteItem` is a part of `Quote`.

Comment: OK that is clear, thank you ! And in terms of conception, how do I call the constructor in my QuoteItem class ? Should I have another main class which initializes first the Quote, then the QuoteItem ?
I'm thinking of putting a method in the Quote class which will initialize all the quote items and loop through them, does that seem correct ?
Noob question, what is a container ?

Comment: @yeye That depends on what you want to achieve. You probably want `Quote` to create the `QuoteItem`

Comment: @yeye Containers are any object that holds an arbitrary number of other objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575925/what-exactly-are-containers-in-python-and-what-are-all-the-python-container