# What is a "container" when I call len()?

Tags: python

I was digging into python functions I would like help understanding what I found.

```
>>> help(len)

Help on built-in function len in module builtins:

len(obj, /)
    Return the number of items in a container.
```

I do not understand what the container would be. I used the following code.

```
>>> example = "art", "women",

>>> print(len(example))

2
```

Comment: In your example, the container is a tuple of two elements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575925/what-exactly-are-containers-in-python-and-what-are-all-the-python-container

Comment: So... thank you for the answer. Did you really need to do the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Any container holding something.

```
>>> ex = [1,2,3]
>>> print(len(ex))
3
>>> ex2 = "a string"
>>> print(len(ex2))
8
>>> ex3 = {1,2,3,4}
>>> print(len(ex3))
4
```

array, string, list, ...